# python Flask session

Tags: python, flask, сессия

Хотел на сайте сделать простой
счетчик, мол заходишь по ссылке просмотры поднимаются
сделал простое приложение

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, make_response, session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'you-newer-guess'


@app.route('/home')
def home(): 
    return "this page is your home"


@app.route('/')
def visit(): 
    if 'visits' in session: 
        session['visits'] = session.get('visits')+1
        print(session.keys())
    else: 
        session['visits'] = 1
    return "Total visits: {}".format(session.get('visits'))

    
if __name__ == ('__main__'): 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

все работает, но не могу понять как сделать проверку, что если пользователь переходил по ссылке счетчик не срабатывал. Или я не в том направлении копаю ?

Comment: Я не понял вопроса. Первая и вторая части противоречат друг другу

Comment: счетчик считает все подряд, например если обновлять страничку то просмотры поднимаются. А надо что бы один пользователь один просмотр